# Auth0 and application session timeout - Session not getting timed out in ASP.NET Core MVC (.NET6)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

We have an ASP.NET Core MVC application (.NET6). We have forms authentication in the application. Now we have integrated Auth0 and it works fine (Forms Authentication code is there but no call is happening to that). We are trying to test our session time out controller. We have configured the session in "startup.cs" file for 15 secods but the session is not getting timed out.

```
namespace Bcc.TP.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private static ILogger _startupLogger;
        private static IReadStoreQueryService _readStoreQueryService;
        private static ICacheService _cacheService;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            HostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IWebHostEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            // TODO : This is not working, session not getting timed out after 15 seconds
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options => options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomModelBinderProvider()));

            services.AddAuth0WebAppAuthentication(options =>
            {
                // Ensure to configure the Domain and ClientId, these are required fields to ensure the SDK knows which
                // Auth0 tenant and application it should use.

                options.Domain = Configuration["Auth0:Domain"];
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];

                // https://auth0.com/blog/exploring-auth0-aspnet-core-authentication-sdk/
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Auth0:ClientSecret"];

                // Extra parameters when logging in
                // https://github.com/auth0/auth0-aspnetcore-authentication/blob/main/EXAMPLES.md#extra-parameters
                options.LoginParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                  {
                      {
                          Configuration["Auth0:connectionParameterName"],
                          Configuration["Auth0:DatabaseName"]
                      }
                  };
            });

            services.ConfigureSameSiteNoneCookies(); // related to Auth0

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddThirdPartyWeb(Configuration);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _startupLogger = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Startup>>();
            _readStoreQueryService = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IReadStoreQueryService>();
            _cacheService = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ICacheService>();

            Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy(); // Auth0

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerUnobservedTaskException;

            // Initialize application data
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                InitializeApplicationData(_readStoreQueryService, _cacheService);
            });
        }


    }
}
```

Following code is not working:-

```
    // TODO : This is not working, session not getting timed out after 15 seconds
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });
```

If we remove the block "services.AddAuth0WebAppAuthentication" and add the following:-
// Note : Session Mgmt "Works"

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });
```

Which means Auth0 is out but session is getting timed out and we could see Session controller kicking in.

Not able to get what needs to be done so that Sessions gets timed out.
We have checked the session settings in Auth0 and they are not of any help for session time out at application level

Comment: When you use Auth0 for authentication, the authentication and session management are handled by Auth0 itself, and not by your application's session settings. Auth0 manages the user's authentication state, and your application relies on the tokens provided by Auth0 to determine whether a user is authenticated or not. As a result, your application's session timeout settings might not take effect when Auth0 is handling authentication.

Comment: If you want to log out the user from Auth0 when the session times out, you'll need to implement custom logic to handle that.To implement session timeout independently of Auth0, you could use `AddCookie` method

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Autho session and application sessions are two different things. Its mentioned on Auth0 documenatation also. https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/architecture-scenarios/sso-for-regular-web-apps/part-3?_gl=1*16wy3hd*_gcl_au*MTE0NTkyNDUzOC4xNjk5NjM4NDc2#session-management

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I have found a way(looks like. I am testing the same now properly) but could you please share more on "AddCookie" method?

Comment: services.AddSession(options =>
 {
     options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
     options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
     options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
 });   Due to this configuration, after 15 seconds, if something was stored in session in code, all the values are killed. So what  I am doing is, when user is Authenticated, I am storing some value in session. All this is happening in Action filter. This seems to be working for me.

Comment: Till the time user is not authenticated, sesison id in session keeps on changing. But once users is authenticated , session id does not changes. This is the correct behaviour. Once session times out, the session id again changes (This is how session works).

Answer (score 0):

```
 services.AddSession(options =>
 {
     options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
     options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
     options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
 });
```

This is working with Auth0 but there is a way to know if session expired or not.

First Option
Till the time user is not authenticated, sesison id in session keeps on changing. But once users is authenticated , session id does not changes. This is the correct behaviour. Once session times out, the session id again changes (This is how session works).

Second Option
Due to this configuration, after 15 seconds, if something was stored in session in code, all the values are killed. So what I am doing is, when user is Authenticated, I am storing some value in session. All this is happening in Action filter.

```
if (context.HttpContext.Session.Get(SESSION_KEY_SID) == null)
            {
                var sid = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == SESSION_KEY_SID)?.Value;
                if (sid!= null)
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Session.Set(SESSION_KEY_SID, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)sid));
                    return;
                }
            }
```

I am saving something from claims. But this is not really required. Any random value can be stored(just to avoid confusion..at times....)